# Alternate keys as primary keys in windows resource kit

Tags: windows

Is there a way to remap underscore (_) key to dash key (-) in windows resource kit remapkey tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about resource kit remapkey tool,
but this worked for me:

1. Download and install the latest version of https://www.autohotkey.com/.
2. Create a new script called underscore.ahk with your favorite text editor.
3. Write the following in the file and save it:

$_::Send, -
$-::Send, _

4. Double-click the file to run the script.
5. If you wish, copy the script (or a link to it) in the Startup folder.

Credits:
https://superuser.com/questions/419736/remapping-shift-space-to-an-underscore
https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=10328